# Differences between two identical PCs

Tags: hardware

We have two identical (HW/SW/filesystem) running PCs.

Suppose we are checking these two PCs at the **exact same time** too.

**The question:** In what do these two machines differ? `/dev/*random` doesn't count!

For ex.: "`ps -e`" would differ, because the processes would get different PIDs during boot.

Another example: "`ls -laR /tmp . /dev | cat -n | sort -R`" would also create unique output since "`-R`" randomizes the order and "`cat -n`" ensures that even if the lines get the same salt at "`sort -R`" the hash would still differ since the line count.

Another example:

```
cat a.sh
echo $$
```

and running it would always give a new number.

Another: "`sysctl -a 2>/dev/null`"

Purpose: just collecting ideas for generating random data. Human flesh (human input) is not allowed :)

Thinking of.. any ways to get the current cpu voltage with "general/basic tools", so no need to install perl modules or other softwares?

Comment: At the least they will differ with Network MAC's address and CPU serial numbers.  But these are not entropy....

Comment: Hard question, thats why I am trying with the community. :)

Comment: But differences are not entropy.  You asked about differences, but hinted about entropy. So, as I demonstrated, you could get an answer about differences, and still not answer your entropy question.  This may be what is known as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If the machines are _identical_ there's no particular reason why `ps -e` run immediately after boot should differ. As soon as you count the delay due to the vagaries of logging in an account you're got human input, and you've discounted that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best sources of entropy are

- Precise timing of external events, especially events which happen often, such as arrival of network packets, interrupts from peripherals, or (shudder) keypresses. With enough measurement precision *nothing* is truely identical. See for example the Hardware Volatile Entropy Gathering and Expansion ([HAVEGE](https://www.irisa.fr/caps/projects/hipsor/)) program.
- Dedicated hardware. For example, modern AMD and Intel CPUs include a [`RDRAND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) instruction which produces a hardware-generated random number.